# Traditional drinks for St Patrick's Day?

Tags: drinking, tradition

[St Patrick's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Patrick's_Day) is celebrated every year on March 17. It brings back those old Irish stories and legends that abound with this Saint.

We all know of some of that traditional Irish drinks that people drink on the Feast of St Patrick, such as [Irish Coffee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_coffee) or drinking [Green Beer](http://www.bettycrocker.com/menus-holidays-parties/mhplibrary/seasonal-ideas/how-to-make-green-beer).

Are there any other St Patrick's Day drinking traditions celebrated on this day?

Comment: Plus, if you put green food coloring in Guinness it wouldn't make a bit of difference! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the Irish really care too much as long as they have a drink in front of them. How about Irish Whiskey and Guinness? Maybe some Irish Coffee, Bailey's or cider. All the Irish I know aren't too picky. I don't think you find too much green beer in Ireland, that's a made up American thing.

[Origins of Green Beer](http://www.foxnews.com/food-drink/2015/03/12/tracing-origin-green-beer.html)

[Ireland's top 10 drinks](http://www.irishcentral.com/culture/food-drink/irelands-top-ten-drinks-of-choice-123606814-237392621)

Comment: I hate to say it but OMG.  I have spent a lot of time in the Caribbean and in one bar for St patricks's day they served green, yes I did say green beer (larger), no one bought it and for a long time thereafter green beer was on offer in the bar - god knows what it did to people's kidneys!